# Alphaville forever young cover version

Tags: identify-this-song, cover

I recently heard over the radio in Sweden a cover version of Forever Young which was really good but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the song's Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forever_Young_(Alphaville_song)#Other_versions), there was a version released this year by Swedish singer UNDRESSD. It can be [viewed on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aflFCldHGg8).